# Preparations for Sin

Tags: final-fantasy-10

After 36 hours of game play, I am preparing to battle Sin.

Is there anything I should know, or go back and get as I prepare for battle?

Comment: Good luck! I remember Sin being much less difficult than other bosses, to be honest. If you got this far, you should be fine. :)

Comment: I spent some time leveling, but certainly not an extreme amount.  I think I still took down Sin before he made a single attack.

Comment: Only 36 hours? I played that game for something like 160...

Comment: I moved through it rather quickly skipping most of the side quests... I may go back after beating Sin...

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure you have all of your overdrives when you go into the fight. If you've unlocked all the of the Aeons(is that what they're called? It's been like 8 years since I played this game) and they have their overdrives.

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much get invincibility throughout the fight with Sin proper, so feel free to unload all your overdrives on the first fight against Jecht/Yevon/Sin (with the two assistant thingies). That's by far the hardest part of the fight. If you can get through that you've pretty much got it licked.

Prepare all your characters and Aeons so that they have full overdrive bars and when the fight starts unload them all into the boss, you ought to get about 9999 damage for each. The Sin battle is significantly harder than those leading up to it, though, so be ready.

If memory serves there's a rare item you can get that reduces the MP cost of all spells to 1MP. You may need to look up on Gamefaqs how to get it. Put it on one of your mages and have them fire Ultima or Holy every single turn. If you've buffed them up well you should get nearly 9999 per turn. If you can sustain this barrage it'll make short work of anything.

Answer (score 0):

The last Sin battle is quite easy because you can cast Reflect on him. Then when he tries to heal himself it just heals you instead :)